# Check if a type has a property

Tags: typescript

I have a custom type and I want to check if it has a certain property without having to create an object of that type.

```js
type Person = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

I can check doing this:

```js
const person: Person = {name: "", age: 0}

if ("name" in person) console.log("They have a name!");
```

What I am trying to do though is let a user pass in a Key and Value to update the Person type but I want the type to be the source of truth for what the valid properties are.

```js
const userInput = {key: "name", "ari"} // valid
// userInput = {key: "job", "milk man"} invalid!

if (userInput.key in Person) // update
else // handle error
```

Comment: Are you wanting to check if the key passed matches a property name for the given class?

Comment: Sort of, I want to know if the `key` passed in from the user can be assigned to type `Person`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already have an object of type Person that you want update, right? As implied by `if (userInput.key in Person) // update`

Comment: I want to know if I can avoid having to create an object to test against and go direct to the `type`. That way the type is the source of truth so I don't have to update it in two places should the `Person` type change.

Comment: Unfortunately no, unless you try to cast it to the Person type and catch a failed cast error. But that is messy and it's better to just make a temp object. Your code will be more readable

Comment: Do you really want to use the comma operator in your user input? If you're talking about doing this _at runtime_ then note that all type metadata is erased in transpilation to JavaScript.

Comment: @Kwright02 what is a "failed cast error"? If you mean the TS error that there isn't sufficient overlap for a type _assertion_ then you can't try and catch that, it's a compiler error.

Comment: I wasn't meaning at the compile level. I may have wrote the wrong words, it's pretty late and I've been up for 16 hours. If you can offer a better explanation that would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the .hasOwnProperty("") function.

```
const userInput = {key: "name", "ari"};
// userInput = {key: "job", "milk man"};

if (person.hasOwnProperty(userInput.key)) {
    // Update
}

else {
    // Handle Error
}
```

Comment: I get the error `TS2693: 'Person' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: Sorry, make the Person lowercase, then it will refer to your object, not the class. I have not edited the code to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I am trying to do, test against the `type` without having to create an object. But other comments have said this is not possible. I'll mark yours as accepted answer.